# Can't get CAPTCHA's to work?

Tags: php, html, forms, captcha, contacts

I have recently looked into using `CAPTCHAs` since I have a contact form I would like to add it to.

However, each captcha seems to be displaying the same issue, which is that once I have implemented the captcha, the textarea where you are supposed to answer the CAPTCHA on **has the PHP code in the textarea itself**.

If anyone could guide me through as well as link me to some captchas that could work, that would be greatly appreciated!

---

Here is what I have so far:

**Form:**

```
<div class="contactform">
        <form class="form" action="mail.php" method="POST">

            <div class="namebox">
            <p class="name">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </p>
            </div>

            <div class="emailbox">
            <p class="email">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </p>
            </div>

            <div class="titlebox">
            <p class="title">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
            </p>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="descriptionbox">
            <p class="description">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea name="description"> </textarea>
            </p>
            </div>

            <br>

            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>

        </form>
        </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$formcontent ="From: $name \n Message: $description";
$recipient = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank you. Your message will be reviewed as soon as possible!";
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any CAPTCHA here. All this is, is a contact form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have not included a Captcha in this example as I have removed the ones that didn't work for me, so you are correct, this is just a contact form.

Comment: were you gone on vacation? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was not, nope, I just didn't see the comment field in this specific area, so I did get a little confused when I first saw some notifications but never saw anything more under the "Answers" section

Comment: Well, what  I think may be happening is, your HTML form, isn't holding the `.php` extension and that's why you have the "PHP code" showing inside it, rather than being parsed. If your file is `.htm` or `.html`, rename it to `.php`. I'm pretty sure that's what it is that is going on here. Let me know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I do realise this is a beyond late answer, but I felt bad for not coming back here. However, I have sorted it out. While this code in specific is not currently in use, I contacted another friend that has quite a bunch of PHP knowledge, mostly just to check and he said the same thing, that the extensions are whats causing it. Cheers for your answers and replies though! :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Don't feel bad, it happens. If you never ask, you'll never get an answer, right? ;-) if you wish the question to be closed and marked as solved that you can accept, I can transcribe my comment to an answer. The choice is yours.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have now accepted your answer as the answer to the question. I appreciate everyones help, but I do believe your answer is the missing link that I will need to add. Cheers once again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *@Fred-ii- So I do realise this is a beyond late answer, but I felt bad for not coming back here. However, I have sorted it out. While this code in specific is not currently in use, I contacted another friend that has quite a bunch of PHP knowledge, mostly just to check and he said the same thing, that the extensions are whats causing it. Cheers for your answers and replies though! :)*

Comment to answer to close the question:

What I think may be happening is, your HTML form, isn't holding the `.php` extension and that's why you have the "PHP code" showing inside it, rather than being parsed.

- If your file is `.htm` or `.html`, rename it to `.php`

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how CAPTCHA works?
will let me explain it to you:
CAPTCHAs protection system works by generating a random string, writing it to an image, then storing the string inside of a session or by some other method. This is then checked when the form is submitted.
[THIS](http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-captchas-php-gd/) article is a valuable source,check it out and it will guide you to creating a secure CAPTCHA.